# AngularJs extracting values from JSON Object and attaching to $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am receiving the following JSON data object

```
{
  "ip": "**Removed**",
  "country_code": "GB",
  "country_name": "United Kingdom",
  "region_code": "ENG",
  "region_name": "England",
  "city": "Plymouth",
  "zip_code": "PL6",
  "time_zone": "Europe/London",
  "latitude": 50.442,
  "longitude": -4.0828,
  "metro_code": 0
}
```

**How do I extract the first two values and attach them to the $scope so that they can be shown in the template when received.**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're getting it via http request your call would be like this:

```
  $http.get("./getData.php").success(function(data) {
      $scope.data = {};                 
      $scope.data["ip"] = data["ip"];
      $scope.data["country_code"] = data["country_code"];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set this whole object to a property on the scope in your controller:

```
$scope.jsonObject = jsonObject;
```

Then in your template, just access it like:

```
<span>{{jsonObject.country_code}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, first store that JSON into one varaible

Var jsonData = {
  "ip": "**Removed**",
  "country_code": "GB",
  "country_name": "United Kingdom",
  "region_code": "ENG",
  "region_name": "England",
  "city": "Plymouth",
  "zip_code": "PL6",
  "time_zone": "Europe/London",
  "latitude": 50.442,
  "longitude": -4.0828,
  "metro_code": 0
}

$scope.firstTwoValues = jsonData.ip+jsonData.country_cody;

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic names u can use smth like this:

```
someDataService.get()
   .then(function(res) {
     var keys = Object.keys(res.data).splice(1,2);
     angular.forEach(keys, function(key){
        $scope[key] = res.data[key];
     });
     return $q.when();
   }
```